# Cassandra OOM crash

Tags: performance, cassandra, out-of-memory, bigdata, cassandra-3.0

I know there are many Cassandra and OOM related problems, but this is a little different from them.

Our company has a test environment for a product, which runs on Cassandra 3.9, in beta stage. This environment is running on a single node, with 4 vCPUs and 8GB of RAM. For 5 months, this environment has been fed with data regularly, about 40k rows in a day, without a single OOM.

A few weeks ago, we decided to load more data to see limits of our test environment and about 500k rows were inserted in a few hours. In result Cassandra has crashed because of OOM. After that, we deleted the 500k rows and application resumed to fed with daily 40k rows again.

But after we performed our load test, although we reverted our changes, we started to encounter OOMs and VM crashes regularly, like 2 times in a week.

My question is, does anybody know why would Cassandra behave like that? It seems that somehow Cassandra has extended its limits and needs more memory than it used to be.

**UPDATE**

There are a few tables in data model, but these are the main two of them, with 80%-90% of read/writes:

```
CREATE TABLE global_events (
    customer_id bigint,
    start_dt timestamp,
    client_id text,
    connected boolean,
    site_id bigint,
    exit boolean,
    is_new boolean,
    is_visitor boolean,
    last_seen timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, start_dt, client_id)
);
CREATE INDEX global_events_connected_idx ON global_events (connected);
CREATE INDEX global_events_site_id_idx ON global_events (site_id);
CREATE INDEX global_events_exit_idx ON global_events (exit);
CREATE INDEX global_events_is_new_idx ON global_events (is_new);
CREATE INDEX global_events_is_visitor_idx ON global_events (is_visitor);

CREATE TABLE local_events (
    customer_id bigint,
    local_id bigint,
    start_dt timestamp,
    client_id text,
    connected boolean,
    exit boolean,
    is_new boolean,
    is_visitor boolean,
    last_seen timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((customer_id, local_id), start_dt, client_id)
);
CREATE INDEX local_events_connected_idx ON local_events (connected);
CREATE INDEX local_events_is_new_idx ON local_events (is_new);
CREATE INDEX local_events_is_visitor_idx ON local_events (is_visitor);
```

There are no TTLs in these tables (so no tombstones), and it's a write-intensive system.

Comment: whats your data model? I would guess if you keep appending to same partitions, the index overhead would be the problem.

Comment: Check your cassandra.yaml settings to see if any cache settings creating memory crunch.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink added data model

Comment: @GangadharKairi do you have any settings in your mind, which can cause this effect?

Comment: @serdar settings like key_cache_size_in_mb and row_cache_size_in_mb etc.

Comment: Those indexes are probably the issue. They are not like relational DB indexes and should be used infrequently and only if the data set fits within a very narrow set of conditions. Thing like `CREATE INDEX global_events_connected_idx ON global_events (connected);` means you will have 2 partitions with ALL the data in it, this is very bad and is most likely your issue. Avoid things with super low cardinality (will have very wide partitions in 2i) and very high cardinality (will have billions of partitions which is slow for compactions with lots of overhead)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't enough information to figure out what the OOM is causing. Usually you should start with your data model and then jvm.options and cassandra.yaml and figure out whats going on. Whats different compared to defaults?

On another note, run from 3.9 like your life depends on it. There is an awesome bug with open file handles once you start repair and it crashes almost every time.

My advice would be to update to 3.11 and use default configuration and then see how it behaves.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will give it a try. By the way, could you provide a link for 3.9 bug?